# Emit signal from separate thread in glib/gtk

Tags: c, gtk3, glib, gobject

I've programmed a GTK3 application in C. To speed up performance I want to put some calculations in separate threads. Currently I have not yet decided how to exactly implement it. But I think I will go with a `GTask` that I will trigger to run in a separate thread.

I want to to emit certain status updates about the calculation progress on my GUI.

They way I imagine this:

I've got a calculation GObject with a do_the_stuff_async() function that triggers the thread/GTask. Ideally, I want to connect to a 'progress-changed' signal which gives me the current status that I can display on my GUI. Also it would be great to trigger an event once the task has finished, which seems doable with a `GTask`

How do I safely emit a signal from a GTask/GThread to my GTK main loop?

Because I have not yet started implementing the asynchronous stuff: Is a GTask a suitable way for this or should I use something entirely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `GTask` is suitable for this.

To emit the signal in a different thread:

1. Store the `GMainContext` of the main thread somewhere, and pass it into the `GTask` as task data.
2. When you want to emit a signal, create a `GSource` with `g_idle_source_new()`, add a callback for it, and attach it to the `GMainContext` of the main thread. That will make the callback be called in the main thread the next time the main thread’s context iterates.
3. The callback should call `g_signal_emit()` as appropriate.

Unless you want to make the `GObject` that you’re emitting the signal from thread safe, you should not pass it to the `GTask` worker thread. My general advice would be to avoid locking by only passing immutable objects to and from the worker thread.

Note that you could use `g_idle_add()` to create an idle `GSource` and add it to the global default `GMainContext` (the one GTK uses in the main thread). However, this makes the use of the `GMainContext` less explicit, and hence makes the code less maintainable. It’s not an approach which I would recommend in general.

Comment: Btw, `g_idle_add` automatically attaches to default context (the GUI one)

Comment: I explicitly avoided suggesting that, as using the default `GMainContext` makes code harder to maintain. It would work, though. I’ll edit my answer to mention this.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall can you plese post a simple example using gtask. I tried to understand the example given on gnome site but didnt get anything, Thank you

Comment: There are some code examples on https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/main-contexts.html.en

Comment: @PhilipWithnall Is there perhaps a new link to the page above, the link isn't alive anymore? I found that link rather useful. If I google "gnome programming guidelines" I find a different page. The "old" guidelines gave a nice user friendly general introduction about serveral topics such as threading GTasks.

Comment: It’s in the process of being moved to the new docs site (see here: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/new-gnome-developer-documentation-website/7134/4). It will likely eventually show up at https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials.html. For now, an archive copy is available at https://developer-old.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/main-contexts.html.en